# no set picture in control.image with uri

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, uri

My Solution Explorer image :

[image]

My code in PopupWinHelper :

```
var img = new Image
{
    BitmapEffect = new DropShadowBitmapEffect(),
    Stretch = Stretch.Fill,
    Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/WpfApplication1;component/images/PopupImage.png"))
};
```

My code in Mainwindow :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    cuswin.PopupWinHelper.ShowPopUp(150,300,"asdad", new Thickness(20));
}
```

Why does this error occur?

Then I'm use :

```
var img = new Image
{
    BitmapEffect = new DropShadowBitmapEffect(),
    Stretch = Stretch.Fill,
    Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/images/PopupImage.png", UriKind.Relative))
};
```

No error. But the picture is not shown in image.

Answer (score 0):

```
Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/WpfApplication1;component/images/PopupImage.png", UriKind.Relative))
```

should work, assumed PopupImage.png is a Resource.

Regards